# Extend Sonar Widget using Iframe into External application

Tags: sonarqube

Is it possible to use one of Sonar widgets from External Application? I was thinking about the below method.

> Call
>
> http://`server`/widget?id=`widget id`&resource=`project key`
>
> From Iframe

Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible, but **this is not an API so it can be removed at anytime without notice**.

The base URL has indeed the following pattern:

```
http://<my_server>/widget?id=<widget_key>
```

, and you can append the widget parameters at the end of the URL.

For instance: http://nemo.sonarqube.org/widget?id=complexity&resource=org.codehaus.sonar:sonar&metric1=complexity&metric2=ncloc

However, if you want to embed those widgets into a third party application, you will have to deal with authentication and permissions if your SonarQube instance is secured.

And once again, please keep in mind that this is not an API.

Comment: Thank you So much..the information Provided by you is well Appreciated.

Comment: WidgetId can be retrieved by looking at the http request params, when clicking on the add widget button in the dashboard editor.